# How to make cell range dynamic in DDE in SAS

Tags: excel, sas, dde

I am trying to format a weekly report using DDE in sas which opens a excel file kept on my desktop location. I want to format the font some of these cells. I have a total column which needs to be formatted every time the new data comes in. But every time this data would come out the range of the "Total" cell would be different. Please refer to the code i am writing

`options noxsync noxwait;`

```
filename sas2xl dde 'excel|system';



data _null_;        
 length fid rc start stop time 8;       
 fid=fopen('sas2xl','s');       
 if (fid le 0) then do;        
 rc=system('start excel');        
 start=datetime();      
 stop=start+10;        
 do while (fid le 0);         
 fid=fopen('sas2xl','s');          
 time=datetime();         
 if (time ge stop) then fid=1;        
 end;        
 end;       
 rc=fclose(fid);       
run;       

data _null_;      
 file sas2xl;        
 put '[open(myfilepath\file.xlsx")]';          
run;            

**I had created a macro using call symput and i am using it here for dynamically changing the row number**  
%macro xyz;         
data _null_;         
 file sas2xl;       
%do i= 1 %to 3;       
 put '[error(false)]';       
 put '[workbook.activate("Sheet1")]';        
 put '[select("r&&rownum&i..c1")]';        
 put '[format.font("Arial",true,false,false,false,1,false,false)]';       
 put '[column.width(0,"c1:c6",false,3)]';       
%end;         
run;
```

ERROR
The code is not working and give me a error like this
DDE session not ready. FATAL:
Unrecoverable I/O error detected in the execution of the DATA step program.      Aborted during the EXECUTION phase.

Can you please tell me how can i go ahead in this

Comment: And how can the cell to work with be identified?

Comment: Hi cindy, the data has a subtotal column which needs to be formatted, but this column may vary with every week's data. There is a total column which needs to be formatted every week. The cell range where this total will lie would change everyweek. So basically I want to make this "Total" dynamic so that i do not have to specify the entire cell and column range everytime i work.

Comment: I would recommend switching over to ODS Tagsets.excelxp. If you want your formula's to be dynamic, you have to have some sort of rule, what's the rule? Would you have the counts in a different cell or can you extract the number of rows from your tables and then create/insert the formula from DDE?

Comment: Try to find an old excel macro reference manual, dating from before the introduction of VBA. That is the set of commands you can use in DDE.

Comment: Hi Reeze, The formula I would use here is first.last. so that I can capture the last "Total" Cell. But, how do i use this new column with the first and last. variable in the DDE

Comment: Hi Reeza, Please refer to the code and let me know what issues it still has

Comment: Hi DirkHorsten , Please refer to my code below